# Excel Run-time error 1004

Tags: excel, runtime-error

I am currently creating a booking system as an ICT project for the ICT IEA Coursework. Im using excel for the booking system and a part of it is this stock list which is like a gallery with images of the products.

A requirement for the project is that when you click on the image, it goes to an individual project page which I tried to do by using a basic macro which switches between pages. However whenever I click on the macro enabled image, the 'run-time error 1004' window comes up.

The coding for the macro is as follows:

```
Sub ipadcoverbuddy()
'
' ipadcoverbuddy Macro
'
    Sheets("ipad coverbuddy").Select
End Sub
```

The line `Sheets("ipad coverbuddy").Select` is higlighted when I click debug after closing the error window.

It works perfectly fine if the sheet tab is not hidden however I want the tab for the sheet to be hidden which means that it wont work.

How do I solve this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the Sheet visible first, and after you finish the process, set the sheet to invisible.

```
Worksheets("ipad coverbuddy").Visible = -1
Worksheets("ipad coverbuddy").Select
Worksheets("ipad coverbuddy").Visible = 0
```